# Rails background job processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backgroundworker, background-process, workling, starling-server

I am using starling as a queue server in my rails application. so each time  i want to call worker method, I have to start starling and workling client from console.

Is there a way where as soon as the passenger is started my workling and starling both get auto started Or preciously when i will call the worker method then only my worling instance will get created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I start up my workling and starling processes in one call using the "god" gem.  It also allows you to setup CPU and memory thresholds.  You might find it useful.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/130-monitoring-with-god